# Getting SHP or SVG from GADM subdivisions within Guyana?

Tags: data, gadm

GADM is a high-resolution database of country administrative areas. I have [downloaded the whole world distribution](http://www.gadm.org/version2) (it is composed of several dBase III files and a big .SHP file).

I am trying to query the GADM database for, given a country, get the first-level administrative divisions. Here is a listing of results I would expect for "Guyana":

- Barima-Waini
- Pomeroon-Supenaam
- Essequibo Islands-West Demerara
- etc.

Now, how I can I get an SHP or SVG map for Guyana and their first-level divisions like [the one in Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Guyana#mediaviewer/File:Guyana_regions_english.png)?
(I don't know about polygons or latitudes, I think I don't need to)

Answer (score 4):

You can download the shapefiles for Guyana from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). Simply select the country from the list and your specific subject such as:

- Roads
- Railways
- Population

I selected **Administrative areas** and received 3 shapefiles with differing levels. The shapefile named "GUY_adm1" will give you the polygon layout as shown in your link. **However**, there seems to be an error in the names of regions from DIVA-GIS as you can see from the image below. I checked other [sources](http://www.guyanagraphic.com/content/regions-guyana) to confirm this. You can easily correct the names for each region by editing the attributes:

[image: Guyana]